# Tomcat 8.0 with eclipse error when try to debug

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

[that's the problem i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTB6B.png)When i try to start the server on eclipse it show me this error

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Stop any other tomcat you have (see process explorer or equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an already running process with one of the required ports:

1. Open cmd/terminal
2. Type '`netstat -tap`' (or `netstat -tuplenao`
   in linux)
3. Find the process id related with port *(8005, 8080,
   8009)* i.e. you will see there `0.0.0.0:8080` so you know *8080* is
   being used
4. If you think this process is not required you can kill
   from windows task manager finding by process id or `kill ${pid}` in
   linux

Comment: When I type netstat -tap no port appears is that a problem ?

Comment: @abachopchop can be udp try -uap or maybe process already died or different user runs rum cmd as admin amd try again

Answer (score 0):

Double click on your Server

```
 ->Overview
    ->Ports
     ->change all the port numbers to whatever you like(8010,8089,8015)
    ->save or CTRL + S
```